# Triangle Tripler

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

Simpler version of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/236812/triangle-of-triangles)

### Task

You must create a program that outputs a triangle of a given size N.

- A triangle is made of 3 identical triangles
- A triangle of size N should be made of N lines
- A triangle's line starts from 1 star, and increases by 2 stars each line

### Test Cases:

```
1 ->

 *
* *

3 ->

     *
    ***
   *****
  *     *
 ***   ***
***** *****

5 ->

         *
        ***
       *****
      *******
     *********
    *         *
   ***       ***
  *****     *****
 *******   *******
********* *********

10 ->


                   *
                  ***
                 *****
                *******
               *********
              ***********
             *************
            ***************
           *****************
          *******************
         *                   *
        ***                 ***
       *****               *****
      *******             *******
     *********           *********
    ***********         ***********
   *************       *************
  ***************     ***************
 *****************   *****************
******************* *******************
```

### Scoring:

This is code-golf so shortest code size wins!

Trailing whitespace is allowed

Credits to Ninsuo for the [puzzle](https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/may-the-triforce-be-with-you)

Comment: Yes, it's not as nearly duplicate as I initially thought. Anyway, we usually link related challenges for the benefit of readers

Comment: Can we use a different character than `*` to create the triangles? And any reason why the input is always a triangular number (which 5 isn't as mentioned by @Giuseppe), since any positive integer works for the intended output?

Comment: rules on leading/trailing whitespace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
*×［］：｛│］∔／│
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=KiVENyV1RkYzQiV1RkYzRCV1RkYxQSV1RkY1QiV1MjUwMiV1RkYzRCV1MjIxNCV1RkYwRiV1MjUwMg__,i=MTA_,v=8)

###### Explanation:

```
*x[]:{|]+/| | Full code (replaced with ASCII)
------------+-----------------------------------------
*           | Push '*'
 x          | Repeat <input> times horizontally
  []        | List of prefixes
    :       | Duplicate
     { ]    | Map over each element
      |     | Palindromize horizontally with 1 overlap
        +   | Add the two lists together
         /  | Anti-diagonalize
          | | Palindromize horizontally with 1 overlap
```

Comment: Anti-diagonalize and palindromize are quite nice primitives.

Comment: @Jonah Canvas is literally designed for ASCII art, so taking advantage of common ASCII art features like diagonals and symmetry is something of a must... *really* comes in handy for these types of challenges!

Answer (score 9):

## Python 3, 74 bytes

```python
lambda n:[print(i//n*f"{i%n*'**'+'*':^{8*n>>i//n}}")for i in range(n,3*n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcndCkAwGAbgW1lK2z7KgZQUN@KnJsZXvFvLieTaJ8/p4@9rdyhrH6Jth3iYc16MQNP7wLgUFwXIJg@nIEkkM0mymZ6a0HX/vW@irQuCBUMEg21VyEuCHqNVlY4f)

Deera Wijesundara
saved 2 bytes by suggesting `print`-based I/O instead of `"\n".join`.

### Explanation

For each `i in range(n,3*n)`, we center `i%n*2+1` asterisks in `8*n>>i//n` spaces and repeat this string `i//n` times.

| `i` | `i%n` | `i%n*'**'+'*'` | `8*n>>i//n` | `i//n` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| n | 0 | `*` | 4n | 1 |
| n+1 | 1 | `***` | 4n | 1 |
| n+2 | 2 | `*****` | 4n | 1 |
| … | … | … | … | … |
| 2n | 0 | `*` | 2n | 2 |
| 2n+1 | 1 | `***` | 2n | 2 |
| 2n+2 | 2 | `*****` | 2n | 2 |
| … | … | … | … | … |

- `i%n*'**'+'*'` is a byte shorter than `(i%n*2+1)*'*'`.
- `f"{s:^{n}}"` is an icky but short way to write `(s).center(n)`.

Comment: You can add print and make it 2 bytes shorter `lambda n:[print(i//n*f"{i%n*'**'+'*':^{8*n>>i//n}}")for i in range(n,3*n)]`

Comment: you can add both io but it'll add 6 more bytes `n=int(input());[print(i//n*f"{i%n*'**'+'*':^{8*n>>i//n}}")for i in range(n,3*n)]`

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
ＮθＦ²«Ｇ⌊θ*↖‖Ｏ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05orLb9IQcNIU6GaizMgP6cyPT9Pw@pRT5eOQqGOgpKWElAFp29@WaqGVWiBT2paCYgflJqWk5pc4l@WWpSTWKABFKr9/9/0v25ZDgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the size.

```
Ｆ²«
```

Repeat twice.

```
Ｇ⌊θ*
```

Draw half of a triangle. The first time, this draws the left half of the bottom left triangle; the second time, the left half of the top triangle.

```
↖
```

Move to the next triangle. (See below as to why this moves left instead of right. This command has no effect on the second iteration.)

```
‖Ｏ
```

Reflect to complete the triangle. On the first iteration, this also reflects the current position to where it needs to be. On the second iteration, this also reflects the bottom left triangle to create the bottom right triangle.

Comment: how do code in charcoal so well? like how do know what to use in the verbose lang of charcoal

Comment: @DialFrost Practice, mostly (after all I've written over 1,000 programs in Charcoal) but obviously the Wiki was very helpful for getting started.

Comment: what wiki? the github page? (i wanna learn a golf lang soon lol)

Comment: @DialFrost Yeah, the wiki on the github.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>20</s> 16 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
·ÅÉ'*×DāRúí.º«.c
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9vc2FiaWX//8K3w4XDiScqw5dExIFSw7rDrS7CusKrLmP//zM) or [verify the test cases in the range \$[1,10]\$](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/R/iquSZV1BaYqWgZO@nw6XkX1oC4en4/T@0/XDr4U51rcPTXY40Bh3edXit3qFdh1brJf/XObTN/j8A).

**Explanation:**

```python
           #  e.g. input=3
·          # Double the (implicit) input-integer
           #  STACK: 6
 ÅÉ        # Pop and push a list of all odd numbers below this
           #  STACK: [1,3,5]
   '*×    '# Map each to that many "*" as strings
           #  STACK: ["*","***","*****"]
D          # Duplicate this list
           #  STACK: ["*","***","*****"],["*","***","*****"]
 ā         # Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping)
           # (which is basically a list in the range [1,input])
           #  STACK: ["*","***","*****"],["*","***","*****"],[1,2,3]
  R        # Reverse it to range [input,1]
           #  STACK: ["*","***","*****"],["*","***","*****"],[3,2,1]
   ú       # Pad the strings of the top copy with that many leading spaces
           #  STACK: ["*","***","*****"],["   *","  ***"," *****"]
    í      # Reverse each string in the list so the spaces are trailing
           #  STACK: ["*","***","*****"],["*   ","***  ","***** "]
     .º    # Overlapping mirror each string
           #  STACK: ["*","***","*****"],["*     *","***   ***","***** *****"]
       «   # Merge the two lists of lines together
           #  STACK: ["*","***","*****","*     *","***   ***","***** *****"]
        .c # Join each line by newlines, and centralize it
           #  STACK: "     *\n    ***\n   *****\n  *     *\n ***   ***\n***** *****"
           # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Excel, 94 bytes

```
=LET(x,SEQUENCE(A1*2),a,REPT(" ",A1*2-x),b,REPT("*",MOD(x-1,A1)*2+1),a&b&REPT(a&" "&a&b,x>A1))
```

[Link to Spreasheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnh0ulZdhbVmX3OTq?e=pSWBt1)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 80 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,x=y=h=n*2)=>y?` *
`[--x+h?x>=y-h&x<=h-y^y<=n&x*x<y*y:(x=h,y--,2)]+f(n,x):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcyxDoIwEADQna9wgl7pGcG4kB58iNFAkFoMaY0Yc/f1NY6G9Q3vMXyGdXzNzzeGeJtScqSCYRLyFHQN1ErX73TWnxG59B23JOhztuRRrmIp5KzZipZGMXkjiKaGS@l@CzRFkcYY1rhM@yXelVMVQPYvx42cNlIdANIX)

#### Patterns

Coordinates:

- \$y\$ goes from \$2n\$ at the top to \$1\$ at the bottom
- \$x\$ goes from \$2n-1\$ on the left to \$-2n+1\$ on the right

The examples below are given with \$n=3\$.

```
x >= y - h        x <= h - y
               
XXXXXX-----       -----XXXXXX       -----X-----
XXXXXXX----       ----XXXXXXX       ----XXX----
XXXXXXXX---  AND  ---XXXXXXXX  -->  ---XXXXX---
XXXXXXXXX--       --XXXXXXXXX       --XXXXXXX--
XXXXXXXXXX-       -XXXXXXXXXX       -XXXXXXXXX-
XXXXXXXXXXX       XXXXXXXXXXX       XXXXXXXXXXX

y <= n            x² < y²
               
-----------       XXXXXXXXXXX       -----------
-----------       -XXXXXXXXX-       -----------
-----------  AND  --XXXXXXX--  -->  -----------
XXXXXXXXXXX       ---XXXXX---       ---XXXXX---
XXXXXXXXXXX       ----XXX----       ----XXX----
XXXXXXXXXXX       -----X-----       -----X-----


-----X-----       -----------       -----X-----
----XXX----       -----------       ----XXX----
---XXXXX---  XOR  -----------  -->  ---XXXXX---
--XXXXXXX--       ---XXXXX---       --X-----X--
-XXXXXXXXX-       ----XXX----       -XXX---XXX-
XXXXXXXXXXX       -----X-----       XXXXX-XXXXX
```

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>39</sup> 37 bytes

```
'* '{~](](=|.)/@,:{.)(>i.@-+/|@i:)@+:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYw9C8IwFEX3/IpHB5M0X0p1CbQ8FZzEwVUylJLSithSujX412ODONzL5cC5z5hp2kJpgYKELdg1SsP5fr1EmgNdPo45VgbNDUq7aM6qXqMSJmBvOQobObmdNBxfs5/e9eyhHsdpqJsuPebJr5w0yJKFD2GynZM2oOIi9UrzzZ74phugheI3KP2DA4lf)

<sup>-2 thanks to Lynn!</sup>

*Includes leading whitespace that can be removed with a few bytes.*

Not super golfy but the concept is fun:

### how

Let's take n=3 as our example:

- `(>i.@-+/|@i:)@+:` Create a single triangle double the requested input size:

  ```
  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
  0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
  0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
  ```
- `](..........{.)` Take the first n lines of that:

  ```
  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
  ```
- `].......,:` And append it to the big triangle, auto-filling the extra rows with zeros:

  ```
  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
  0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
  0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0

  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  ```
- `(=|.)/@` Reverse rows of the little triangle and check where the planes are still equal:

  ```
  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
  0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
  0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0

       = elementwise?

  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

             v

  1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
  1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
  1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
  1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1
  1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1
  1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
  ```
- `'* '{~` Convert to asterisks and spaces:

  ```
        *      
       ***     
      *****    
     *     *   
    ***   ***  
   ***** *****
  ```

Comment: You can replace `+|.` by `=|.`, then get rid of `2|` and invert `' *'` to `'* '`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 114 bytes

```python
def f(n,x=1):[print([n*(p:=" "),(t:=(s:=p*(~-n-i))+"*"+"**"*i+s)+p][x]+t)for i in range(0if x and f(n,0)else 0+n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1BCsMgFET3PcXHlV8NGEKhCOlFjItAtBXKj0QXKaW9uo3tYhbDPN6kZ7mvNFzSVuviAwROah97NDZtkQq3JHgyIwOGihcz8mzGJPinoy4iSibYEcFElBllcnZ3smBYN4gQCbaZbp7rGGCHmZafXaN/ZA9aErrayOJzabDt1aDOqtfOnOD/HthEr7a/obtOxPB0KFrH@gU)

### Less-golfed version

```python
def f(n, drawingTopPart=True):
    for i in range(n):
        space = " "
        spacing = space*(n-i-1)
        stars = spacing + '*' + '**' * i + spacing
        print(n*space + stars) if drawingTopPart else print(stars + space + stars)
    if drawingTopPart:
        f(n, False)
```

Comment: Is “0+n” necessary?

Comment: @ophact I couldn't think of any other way to do a singular conditional recursive call

Comment: You can do `0if x and f(n,0)else 0+n`=>`x and f(n,0)or n`, since the function never returns anything, it's value is None which is falsy, which means that `n` is always the value of the expression

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 70 bytes

```ruby
->n{a=[]
n.times{|i|puts" "*n+b=(?**i-=~i).center(n*2)
a<<b*2}
puts a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOtE2OpYrT68kMze1uLoms6agtKRYSUFJK087yVbDXksrU9e2LlNTLzk1ryS1SCNPy0iTK9HGJknLqJYLpFQhsfZ/WrRp7H8A)

Prints the single triangle as it iterates while building up an array of double triangles.

Then dumps a printout of the array at the end.

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 86 bytes

```julia
n/k=1:n.|>j->((s=" "^(k-j))*" "*"*"^(2j-1)*s)^(1+(n==k))
~n=n./[2n,n].|>l->println.(l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBCsIwFET3nkK6mh9N6q@4EX4uIgZcNgmDWAUX0qvHlAePt5jJnzo/9Nsax2J6ZfjF7COw2LAfEorPIq6n6yRM2au4RRL0AJoVkd1KYxhvE4@893f18fma@a4MqNJWaJ/gvOmySU/S/g)

Golfing [David Scholz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242928/101725)'s answer (cannot comment under other people solutions yet!)

Basically got rid of `join` by nesting the `println` call. `println` also gives you trailing `\n` for free. Finally I removed `i` iteration index as it can be expressed in terms of `j`

Comment: This is really clever! (I'll upvote in 11 hours, I've used mine all :p)

Comment: aha thanks! :D

also, the other thing to point out is that `△` counts for 3 bytes, simply replacing it saved 6 bytes

Comment: Yes indeed. I didn't know that one could remove the brackets for two arguments as well!

Comment: you can even do it for three arguments [tio](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P9EqySrZNlE7STv5f0FRZl6JhqGVkZWx5n8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) NumPy, 95 bytes

```
lambda n:where((t:=tril(1>tri(4*n)[::-1])[2*n:])^(t[::-1]&t[:,n:n+1]),*'* ')
from numpy import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY1BCsIwFET3niIUsT-xFVtcSKBepK1SsaGR5ieEX6RncVMQvZO3MRBn84aZgXl-3EyDxeWlquY9kcqP38vYmeutYygfQ-97AJIVeT1CcQqAg0BeS5kXLa9LgbLlZ6AYbAIzlLgNXSZSwVK-Ut4ahpNxM9PGWU_if7N2XiNB0mCyu1uNYDoHSfSZgmLPg-J2WSJ_)

##### Old [Python](https://www.python.org) NumPy, 99 bytes

```
lambda n:[r:=tri(n),z:=0*r,l:=1-r[::-1]]and where(bmat("z l r z;l r l r"),*'* ')
from numpy import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LU1LCoMwFNz3FI9QMAmx6K6k5CTqIlaDKebDI1L0Kt0Ipb1Tb1OLHZjPYoZ5vOOchuDXp1H1a0omP3-uo3Ztp8HLCqVKaKlnYpGq4ChGqcocKynzsmm07-A-9NjT1ulEyQIjICyXn24kTPCMQ8YOBoMDP7k4g3UxYOL_q2NE67dl7cnpFqynTkdK9iwMLQu2Ye-u6-5f)

Returns a numpy array of "*"s and " "s.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 58 bytes

```julia
!n=1:2n.|>i->((s=' '^(2n-i))*'*'^2(~-i%n)*"* $s")^-~+(i>n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcdBCsIwEAXQfU8xLUpmIhGTZaE5SqBQhS9hLE0FC6VXj@Lbvec7Y/SfWlsdfB/0uke4yFwGQyZxUAcRa6xJgQ@Hs4rtLJ1KJ8kdF0ZUqY/XQiAo@d7fGvqZUOY8btxC/p8X6JqVpbnrVL8)

output is a list of strings

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 79 bytes

```
n->for(i=1,m=2*n,print(Strchr([32+10*(i<=n||i+abs(j)>m&&i>-j)|j<-[1-m..i-1]])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcyxCsIwEADQXzk6lLs2V5oWJ5v8hGPoEIXoFRND7CL036Pg@JaXfRG@5xrA1MQ2vAqK0SqaqUsqF0k7XvZyexR089TrsUNZTDoO6f31jRvZ2LZieaNjW9hpjsMgrNeViKrP@flBD2zhP3lofmjoDAE9KXBawazgpECPK9Uv)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 96 bytes

```python
lambda n:'\n'.join(' '*(d:=2*n-1-i)+(c:='*'*(1+i%n*2))+('  '*d+' '+c)*(i>=n)for i in range(n+n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBCsIwEEbhq2QjM5NQoRVBAulJuomN0RH9E0I3nj5m9/h49Xe8Ci632noOW//E7z1FA08b6PwuCiZDlpMPi8U0TyqOdx/IDpydnmAXGURmXMmN1@1iWdcAyaUZNQrTIp4PhoNIr01xcObr6D8)

Comment: [90 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcoxDoMwDAXQq3ipYjswQFWpispJogyIkNbLJ4pYOH3K@vTqdf4OPN@19Z73QoUhIdZmONmRU85hmRXjNJp43sLi9MbJ2wM6iwwaHd0t@y1F@yAkKUcjIwO1Fd@d4SGpF35J/wM "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 54 bytes

```
.+
$**
.
$._$*_$.'$* $`*$`$.'$* ¶
_+
$&$%'¶$%' 
_
 
O`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@bS0VLi0uPS0UvXkUrXkVPXUVLQSVBSyUBwjy0jSseqERNRVX90DYgocAVz6XA5Z/w/78hlzGXKZehAQA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.+
$**
```

Convert the input to a string of asterisks.

```
.
$._$*_$.'$* $`*$`$.'$* ¶
```

Create a triangle of asterisks indented by underscores. `$._$*_` is the string of asterisks replaced by underscores. `$.'$*`  is the space padding on either side of the triangle. `` $`*$` `` is the triangle.

```
_+
$&$%'¶$%'
```

Duplicate each line. `$&$%'` ends up keeping the first line the same, while the `$%'`  causes the second copies of the lines to have an extra copy of the triangle, but without the indent.

```
_
```

Convert the underscores back to spaces.

```
O`
```

Sort the lines into order. This puts the lines with the most spaces first, thus grouping the top triangle's lines back together (and also the remaining lines of the bottom double triangle of course).

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 41 bytes

Prompts for n

```
(⌽0 1↓m),m←⊃(-⍳2×n)↑¨(m,¯1+2×m←⍳n←⎕)⍴¨'*'
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tv8ajnr0GCoaP2ibnaurkAsUfdTVr6D7q3Wx0eHqe5qO2iYdWaOTqHFpvqA0UAMv3bs4DUX1TNR/1bjm0Ql1L/T/QJK7/aVyGXGlcxkBsCgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `C`, 35 bytes

```
λhd›×*;→ẋė:£ƛ←†;¥ƛ←†:?d‹nhd-ð*JȮJ;J
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJDIiwiIiwizrtoZOKAusOXKjvihpLhuovElzrCo8ab4oaQ4oCgO8KlxpvihpDigKA6P2TigLluaGQtw7AqSsiuSjtKIiwiIiwiNSJd)

### Explanation

```
λhd›×*;→  Simple Lambda
λ         Start lambda
 h        Get head
  d›      Double and add 1
    ×*    Repeat it "*" time
      ;→  Close lambda and set it to var.

ẋė:£ƛ←†;  Top triangle
ẋė        Make an empty list with length n and generate tuple (index, item)
  :£      Duplicate tuple and set it to the register
    ƛ     Map through tuple of (index, item)
     ←†;  Get var, call it and close lambda

¥ƛ←†:?d‹nhd-ð*JȮJ;J  Bottom left ans right triangle
¥ƛ                   Get register (index, item) and start a mapping lambda
  ←†:                Get var, call it and duplicate
     ?d‹             Double n and increment by one
        hd-          Get head, double and decrement by one
           ð*        Repeat space that many times
             J       Join the left triangle row with spaces
              ȮJ     Get second to last item (left triangle row) and join
                ;J   Join the top triangle with the bottom triangles

C flag centers everything with spaces.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org/), 129 bytes

```
l="\n"
△(n,k)=((i,j)->(" "^(k-j+1)*"*"^i*" "^(k-j))^(n==k ? 2 : 1)).(1:2:2n,1:n)
~n=print(join(△(n,2n),l),l,join(△(n,n),l))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tcw7CkIxEEbh/q4iTDV/nCtOykB0IxKwzINRRMHqLsONuCM3EkURhFN9xanXXg56G6Mn2htNz/uDTRoSc5GKecvkKHOb60rhyVMu/idAZkupuZ0LLjoF1qwxxGCi0TAtlk7nYheux2L8PQeD9HfyZx/CWFg3GC8)

I had a hard time with this one, any optimizations are highly appreciated!

The function `△` takes two arguments `n,k` whereby `n` is the size of the triangle. The parameter `k` determines the number of whitespaces for each row of the triangle.

I have not found a way to get  rid of the `join` operator, which joins the array of strings with `\n` as a separator. This costs me 8 bytes already.

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `C`, 12 bytes

```
d~∷×*øĊDZvṄJ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJDIiwiIiwiZH7iiLfDlyrDuMSKRFp24bmESiIsIiIsIjUiXQ==)

### How?

```
d~∷×*øĊDZvṄJøĊ⁋
d               # Double the (implicit) input
 ~∷             # Filter-keep for only odd numbers (the number is implicitly converted into a range [1,n])
   ×*           # Repeat an asterisk that many times for each
     øĊ         # Pad each with spaces to center
       D        # Triplicate
        ZvṄ     # Zip the top two copies together, and join by spaces
           J    # Join these two lists together
                # C flag centers and joins by newlines
```